# Login issue using password hash and password verify in php

Tags: php, php-password-hash

**Signup code:**

```
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $contact = $_POST['contact'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO `tbl_user`(`first_name`, `last_name` , `email` , `password`,`contact`, `address`) VALUES
        ('$first_name','$last_name','$email','$hashed_password','$contact','$address')";
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,$query);
```

**Login code :**

```
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `tbl_user` WHERE `email` = '$email'";
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
    if (password_verify('$password', $row['hashed_password'])) {
        echo 'Password is valid!';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid password.';
    }
```

But everytime it is showing Invalid Password even if i enter the correct credentials.

Comment: you are fetching an array and not giving an index number

Comment: Not sure how string interpolation works in php but check what you have stored in the db. Could be you're literally storing the string `"$hashed_password"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error: `'$password'` instead use it as just `$password`.

**Change this to:**

```
if (password_verify('$password', $row['hashed_password'])) {
```

**This:**

```
if (password_verify($password, $row['hashed_password'])) {
```